# How to find the summation of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i)^{2}/[(2i+1)^{2}]$$? Here [.] doesn't represent Greatest Integer Function. I know the series expansions of $cos(x)$,$sin(x)$,$tan(x)$,$tan^{-1}(x)$,$ln(1+x)$,$ln(1-x)$,etc. But I don't know which series expansion to apply here to find the summation? I am confused that the series expansion of which function will work here. Also I don't think that the series is an Arithmetic,Geometric and a Harmonic series. So, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{(2 k+1)^2} & =\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(2 k+1)^2-2(2 k+1)+1}{(2 k+1)^2} \\
& =\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n\left[1-\frac{2}{2 k+1}+\frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{4}\left[n-2 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2 k+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
By Digamma function, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2 k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\psi^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)
$$
and $$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{8}\left(-2 \psi^{(1)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)+\pi^2-8\right)
$$
where $\psi^{(0)}(.)$ and $\psi^{(1)}(.)$ denotes the Digamma function and its first derivative.

Hence we can conclude that $$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{(2 k+1)^2}= \frac{1}{32}\left[8 n-8 \psi^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)+8 \psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-2 \psi^{(1)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)+ \pi^2-8\right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @Lai's answer, for large values of $n$

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{(2 k+1)^2}$$ $$S_n=\frac{n-\log(n) } 4+\frac{8-8 \gamma +\pi ^2-16 \log (2)}{32} -\frac{5}{16 n}+\frac{17}{96 n^2}-\frac{23}{192
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which is in a relative error smaller than $0.01$% as soon as $n>5$